# Application's monitor/screen changed event?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, screen-resolution

I have a `DataGrid` in my WPF application. I am setting `DataGrid`'s maximum width relative to resolution of screen in which application currently resides in.

My solution works fine when user launches the application on primary monitor but the problem comes when user drags the application to second monitor. I need an event which can tell me when the application is moved to a new monitor so that I can reset the `DataGrid`'s maximum width according to current monitor's resolution. How can I do that?

Comment: surely you just want to know when your app is resized

Comment: What will you do when the window stradles the boundary between two monitors?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes you are right, so my approach towards the problem was wrong. App size will do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [LocationChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.locationchanged.aspx) event?